# NullPointerException on save(flush:true) when lazy loading is enabled

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

When I enable lazy loading for some domain classes in my Grails application (using WebLogic), some transactions stop working. The code always fails at different stages, but so far it only did so at save(flush: true) and findAll(), even though these were applied to classes where lazy loading isn't even enabled. It works fine when I disable lazy loading for all classes. I know flush:true should be avoided anyway, but I don't know what causes this problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.flushSession(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:272)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1101.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:923)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:906)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:74)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:237)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor971.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.doInHibernate(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:196)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:140)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:110)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:234)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:154)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save$17.call(Unknown Source)
    at [myOwnCode].save()
        [...]
```